# Playing different sounds with different buttons

Tags: android, eclipse

I have four buttons in total, i.e btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4. Meanwhile i have three sounds. btn1 stops/pauses all the sounds. btn1 plays sound1 and when i press btn2 or btn3 sound1 should stop and play the respective sound according to which button was pressed. I am trying to do it with the following code:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        mp1.pause();
        mp2.pause();
        mp3.pause();

    }
});

btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (mp1.isPlaying()) {

            mp1.pause();
        } else {
            mp2.pause();
            mp3.pause();
            mp1.setLooping(true);
            mp1.start();
        }

    }

}
);

btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        if (mp2.isPlaying()==true) {

            mp2.pause();
        }else{
        mp2.setLooping(true);
        mp2.start();
        mp3.pause();
        mp1.pause();
        }
    }
});

btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        if(mp3.isPlaying()==true){

            mp3.pause();
        }else{
        mp3.setLooping(true);
        mp3.start();
        mp1.pause();
        mp2.pause();}
    }
});
```

}

P.S i'm purposely using onclicklistener

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: If you're not trying to overlap sounds, there's no need to use multiple audio players. Just use a single one and feed it the correct URI depending on which button is pressed.

Comment: That way the app crashes, just tried.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- Replace the pause calls within the else statements with calls to stop().
- Add a call to prepare() for the mp being started in each else statement.
- Move the calls to stop() before the call to prepare.

Each onClick method will look something like:

```
    if (mp1.isPlaying()) {
        mp1.pause();
    } else {
        mp2.stop();
        mp3.stop();
        mp1.setLooping(true);
        try {
            mp1.prepare();
            mp1.start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```